# WPF definition of FontSize

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, fonts

I know that in WPF, FontSize = 1/96 of an inch (same as 1 pixel I think).  Is the FontSize dimension the height, the width, or diagonal size of a character?  I would guess it's the font height, but the [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize.aspx) doesn't really indicate what it is.

Also, is there an easy way to get the height and width of a font size?

**Answer:**
So it looks like the FontSize is the height, and the width can only be determined (without knowing the actual character) on monospaced fonts since proportional fonts have varying widths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are referring to Font Size as used in Typefaces for Typography.

You can read about it here: [Wikipedia: Typeface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeface)

> The size of typefaces and fonts is traditionally measured in points;[2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fcbb12f8-2c28-4621-a763-56af34fe2588) point has been defined differently at different times, but now the most popular is the Desktop Publishing point of 1⁄72 in (0.0139 in/0.35 mm). When specified in typographic sizes (points, kyus), the height of an em-square, an invisible box which is typically a bit larger than the distance from the tallest ascender to the lowest descender, is scaled to equal the specified size.[3] For example, when setting Helvetica at 12 point, the em square defined in the Helvetica font is scaled to 12 points or 1⁄6 in (0.17 in/4.3 mm). Yet no particular element of 12-point Helvetica need measure exactly 12 points.

A note...72 as stated in this Wikipedia article is what WinForms used. WPF switched to 96.

As for the second part of your question, I found this resource from an [MSDN Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fcbb12f8-2c28-4621-a763-56af34fe2588):

```
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
            textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1),  
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface(textBox1.FontFamily.ToString()),
             textBox1.FontSize,
            Brushes.Black 
            );
```

... formattedText.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace;

... formattedText.Height;

Comment: So it sounds like the FontSize is indeed the height and the width can only be determined (without knowing the actual character) on monospaced fonts.  Thanks!